# 圧が強い what's the meaning?

Tags: expressions, slang, culture

What exactly means to describe someone saying "圧が強い" (atsu ga tsuyoi) . I know that's something related with "the person has a strong pressure" or "the pressure in that person is strong" but I was wondering about what is the real connotation for this expression.

Comment: Aside from its literal meaning, it has some tricky uses as slang, and it's hard to write a good answer without proper context. Please provide the full context including the full sentence.

Comment: 「あの人圧が強いですね」
actually was in a very casual situation when someone was commenting absently about other person. I thought it could be a slang because I couldn't exactly the meaning. They are close friends so I don't believe is a bad thing.

Answer (score 3):

Basically this 圧 is a figurative and humorous expression that refers to one's "energy" or "aura". The implication of 圧が強い depends on the context. If it's negative, it implies "oppressing", "noisy and annoying", "scary", "over-confident and rude", etc. If it's neutral or positive, it implies "eager", "looks full of confidence", "has strong presence", etc. This is a rather recent slangy expression, and it's probably not included in a serious dictionary.

Comment: Thank you! I'm having some problems with slangs lately. I started to learn the Formal language but the daily language is being hard to understand.